# How to send an email from a website using PHP?

Tags: php, email, web, html-email, mailto

I have developed a website and want to send emails from the website domain 
I have configured mail function before it worked well then but after few months its not working here is my code

```
$email_from = 'xxx@domainname.lk';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Visitor";
$email_body = "new visitor".

$to = 'qqq@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
$headers .= "From: $email_from \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');
```

Comment: does it give you an error?

Comment: goto cpanel and click on webmail and open horde or roundcube or squirreMail (click on any one of these) and send email manually. if email send then error in your code otherwise contact your host support..

Comment: no @NelsonOwalo code is runnig correctly and bottom line html tags also run successfully

Comment: @BilalAhmed email is sending by manually but not sending by code

Comment: Talk to your hosting provider, sometimes they block email sending or maybe Their servers got reported as spammers, I suggest to use PHPMailer it gives more control on how to send email including authentication, also allows you to use smtp protocol and send email directly from a real account which include some security details added to the email message headers.

Comment: after `mail()` do a `print_r(error_get_last());` and add what that gives

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: @JonnathanQ i have talked to service providers and they sent me an email with new configured settings but im new to php therefore cant find wht to change here is what they sent

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi i just added a return value as follow   if( $retval == true ) {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }else {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }

Comment: and it showing the message sent successfully but not receiving any email

Comment: @NayanaLakshitha ok I got it, well, just make sure to include basic headers to avoid be reported as spam take a look at Amir’s answer, also check your spam folder

Comment: @NayanaLakshitha check in your spam folder?

Comment: Finally found it in spam folder and mails are there @JonnathanQ

Comment: Finally found it in spam folder and mails are there @NelsonOwalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the value of $email_body variable should end with semicolon (;) and also $headers  should be written like below

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
      'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: this was the answer which i finding man thanks a lot